# How to undo git remove after commit?

Tags: git

I have done a `git rm -r path/`. I have commit it, and after that I have seen that I have not done `git rm --cached`. I have searched for going back, and I have done also: `git reset --soft 'HEAD^'` 2 times. Now I see that I have got back on my git tree, but I do not see the removed files...

```
* <I_do_not_know_the_head> commit after removing files   (1)
* <I_do_not_know_the_head> commit before removing files  (2)
* <I_do_know_the_head> current commit                    (3)
* ... other commits                                      (4)
```

I am now at `(3)` and I do not see the commits `(1)` and `(2)`. I want to get to back `(1)` and then get the removed files. The problem is that I think I have done some other changes, too, not just removed those files.

How to go back to the last commit and then just add the removed files? Please help, I do not want to loose commits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo the last Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit)

Comment: From that question I took `git reset --soft 'HEAD^'`... How to go back?

Comment: Doesn't matter. `git reset --hard <commit_id_of_2>` is the answer. It doesn't matter whatever else you have done, or whatever state your repo is in. Just type `git reset --hard <commit_id_of_2>` to go back to 2.

Comment: I have not the id of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--soft` is your problem. That leaves the working directory in its current state. You want `--hard`.

```
git reset --hard <commit_id_of_2>
```

> Why do I want --hard? I do not have the id of 2..

You want `--hard` because that moves the working directory to the state of the commit you're moving to.

You'll have to use `git reflog` to figure out the commit ID of the commit you want to go back to. There are tons of questions on here about how to use `git reflog` if `git reflog --help` isn't enough.